# Python Fabric module usage

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

Trying to use [`Fabric`](https://www.fabfile.org/) module for a Python script that speaks with the remote machine to run various commands. I'm planning to use `Fabric` as a module to establish and run the commands over `ssh`. Is it good practice to use `Fabric` as a regular Python module `from fabric import Connection` and run the script directly like `python script.py`

I have tested this and it works fine.

Comment: Which python version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabric2 is what you need to use with python 2.7+ . Install it by running `pip install fabric2` from the command line!

Then create a `fabfile.py` and with the following code:

```
@task
def deploy(ctx, env=None):
    try:
        with connection(host=REMOTE_HOST, user=REMOTE_HOST_USERNAME,) as c:
            c.run('whoami')
            c.run('echo "do what you want to do"')
            c.run('mkdir new_dir')
    except AuthenticationException as message:
        print(message)
    except SSHException as message:
        print(message)
```

Go to the directory where you `fabfile.py` resides and execute this command from the command line:

```
fab deploy
```

**UPDATE**

You can put the deploy() function inside `main.py`

```
from fabric import Connection as connection, task
from paramiko import AuthenticationException, SSHException


def deploy():
    try:
        with connection(host='faceai-uat', user='admin.peshmerge') as c:
            c.run('whoami')
            c.run('echo "do what you want to do"')
            c.run('mkdir new_dir')
    except AuthenticationException as message:
        print(message)
    except SSHException as message:
        print(message)

def main():
    print("Start deploying")
    deploy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Execute the file by `python3 main.py` from the command line!

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to use fabric in a normal python script and invoke as standard python script rather than using fab command